# Passing environment variables to XMonad spawn

Tags: environment-variables, xmonad

It is my understanding that when invoking `spawn "string command"` in `xmonad`, the argument `"string command"` is actually passed to `/bin/sh`.
Is there a way to change this behavior ?

More specifically, is it possible to make the instance of the interpreter  called by `spawn` aware of some predefined environment variables (typically, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`)?
Of course, it is always possible to resort to `spawn "$VARIABLE=stuff; export $VARIABLE; string command"`, but it bothers me that the variabe should be created and exported each time.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly answering your first question, the `safeSpawn` function in `XMonad.Util.Run` (in `xmonad-contrib`) will run a command without passing it to a shell.

However, that shouldn't make much of a difference as far as environment variables are concerned. In both cases, the spawned command should inherit the environment of the XMonad process (which the shell's startup/rc files could tweak in the case of spawn).

It's possible to set the environment of the started process with general Haskell facilities, e.g. `System.Posix.Process.executeFile` (and `System.Environment.getEnvironment` if you want to make a modified copy of the XMonad process' environment).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now, let's say I already started the process, and that I would like to pass environment variables to the "environment of the XMonad process" (if that makes senses). It seems that `System.Posix.Process.executeFile` is the right tool but can you give me a simple example of how I could use it? Suppose I created a file with `$VARIABLE=stuff; export VARIABLE` if that helps.